# jQuery: multiple live event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

How do I do the live event (for when new content is injected) with the new way of doing multiple jQuery events:

```
$('.foo', this).bind({
    click: function() {
        //do thing
    },
    mouseover: function() {
        //do other thing
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        //do other other thing
    },
    focus: function() {
        //do other other other thing
    }
});
```

For example in the above I need any content to be bound with the click and all the other events too.

Basically, I'm trying to avoid writing:

```
$('.foo', this).live('click', function() {
     //do thing
  }
});
$('.foo', this).live('mouseover', function() {
    //do other thing
  }
});
$('.foo', this).live('mouseout', function() {
    //do other other thing
  }
});
$('.foo', this).live('focus', function() {
    //do other other other thing
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want each event to do unique stuff, you're going to have a verbose task on your hands. If you needed each event to do the same thing, this would be a much shorter task. You can bind multiple events, but it's still going to be somewhat verbose:

```
$('.foo', this).live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else
  if (e.type == 'mouseout') {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

And again, if they all did *the same thing*, this would be simpler:

```
$('.foo', this).live('mouseover mouseout', function(){
  // do something on both events
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4):

.........

```
$('.fastlook', this).live('click', function() {
    // more code.......
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to assign multiple events, just separate them with space, eg:

```
$("selector").live('click mousemove mousedown', function(){
  // more code.............
});
```

..........

> eventTypeA string containing a
>   JavaScript event type, such as "click"
>   or "keydown." As of jQuery 1.4 the
>   string can contain multiple,
>   space-separated event types or custom
>   event names, as well.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, my fault, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Smickie: i have updated my answer after having a look at your updated question, see the Edit part in my answer, thanks :)